# Interpreting SPSS multiple regression output

Tags: regression, interpretation

Help please!

I've conducted a hierarchical multiple regression analysis on variables that predict 1-year PANSS score.

As seen below, all models appear non-significant, which doesn't make sense as one of the variables I'm entering is baseline PANSS score that should have predictive value. Hence I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

May I know:

1. Can I still interpret a significant independent predictor (i.e. ASDASQ in Model 3) if all models/other values are non-significant?
2. Should I be using other methods like excluding constant from the equation/pairwise deletions? These tend to give more significant results but I'm not sure if it'll be meaningful, and the variance explained (80+%) don't really make sense.
3. How is it possible to have pre-test measures not predict post-test measures?

Thank you very much! Any response would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]